# Create signed and notified MacOS installer for .net core console app

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I have read heaps of advice and related problems, but haven't stumbled upon exact one that troubles me. The problem is straightforward: I have a console app written in .Net Core 3.1, which I would like to distribute to MacOS, among others. Hence, I need an installer. Ideally, the whole process shall be script-based, no clicking. Yep, CI. My steps:

1. `dotnet publish -c Release -r osx-x64` (when done on Windows, I add the `chmod +x` to allow execution - no caveat here)
2. pack the whole `bin/Release/osx-x64/publish` directory into an `.app` file (using Platypus for now just to make sure the whole `.app` thing is valid). At this point, clicking on the app actually runs it as expected (apart from the Untrusted developer warning).
3. I have a valid 3rd Party Mac Developer Application certificate, which I use to sign the `.app` and all files within (using a simple script). My entitlements are scarce (basically just the ones [listed in Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos-notarization-issues)).
4. `codesign -vvv --deep-verify MyApp.app` returns nice `valid on disk` and `satisfies its Designated Requirements`
5. Another script then compresses the `.app` into a `.zip` archive and uploads it for notarization, which fails. Reason: `Invalid package`. Running `spctl -vvv --assess --type exec MyApp.app` returns `rejected`, so no surprise.

I have learnt that Invalid package may mean almost anything, as it just don't passes a whitelist of allowed stuff and it is not really possible to indicate where it got wrong (would have to list a rejection reason for each and every rule).

It might be insufficient set of entitlements, as my list only contains the 'default' values per MS documentation. However, I have also tried to create a simple `Hello world` console app to minimize anything going on inside - and sure, `Invalid package`. So it shouldn't be that my app is trying to do something that is not listed in the entitlements.

Which leaves us for... **Hardened Runtime is not enabled?** I haven't found any explicit way to enable it in .net core console app (the only reference was for Xamarin.Mac, which is not applicable here IMO). Neither a way to verify that this is the problem indeed. But I don't expect MS to put so much effort into making .net core cross-platform and then throwing it all away just because Apple mandates Hardened Runtime.

I have tried building on both Windows and Mac, no help. My "Mac" is 10.15 Catalina in a VM (could this be an issue?).

Can anyone please help me, set me on a correct path or show me some piece of documentation I have been missing? I cannot believe that it is impossible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: I must have been blind reading Apple documentation. The thing is, you only get `Invalid package` when querying the notarization results as pages (`xcrun altool --notarization-history 0 -u USER -p PW`). However, when you query your concrete request (`xcrun altool --notarization-info REQUEST_ID -u USER -p PW`), you get `Invalid package` as well, but also a URL pointing to a JSON containing debug info. Using that I was able to identify and remediate my issue.

So, Apple could definitely make their SW publishing process developer-friendlier, but the tools are there. Just double-check.

Comment: how were you able to get around the hardening of the application? If I enable it it breaks my application, read the microsoft docs that says I need to add the entitlements to the app host but could not find how to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos-notarization-issues

Comment: It turned out hardening was not an issue at all (.net core desktop app). I used a wrong type of certificate. If you use xamarin, [this might be helpful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/macos-hardened-runtime-notary/).